# Gems installed under bundler folder are not loaded in terminal by default. Any way it can be loaded automatically?

Tags: ruby, shell, rubygems, bundler

I'm installing a gem from github source using bundler and trying to execute its executable in Terminal, for which it says Gem not found exception. Is there any way that the gems installed under bundler folder gets loaded automatically instead of adding up in PATH variable ?

Comment: How exactly did you install that gem?

Comment: using bundler @spickermann

Comment: And do you run `bundle exec command` or just `command`?

Comment: using ```bundle install``` @spickermann

Comment: @SanjeevKumar what is the actual error? Are you requiring the gem first before trying to use it?

Comment: @engineersmnky I'm trying to execute its CLI executable

Comment: Maybe you should specify the gem and the error. There's not much to go on here. Also I would recommend using `gem install xxxxxx` rather than bundler in this case

Answer (score 0):

if you manage all your rubygems dependencies through bundler, use `bundler exec` to run the rubygems binaries.

for instance if you install [`cowsay`](https://github.com/johnnyt/cowsay) u  sing bundler, then you `Gemfile` will look like

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "cowsay"
```

then install the dependencies with bundler, like

```sh
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using bundler 2.1.4
Fetching cowsay 0.3.0
Installing cowsay 0.3.0
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `./gems`
```

now you can execute `cowsay` using bundler, like

```sh
$ bundle exec cowsay stackoverflow.com
 ___________________
| stackoverflow.com |
 -------------------
      \   ^__^
       \  (oo)\_______
          (__)\       )\/\
              ||----w |
              ||     ||
```